# How do I change animation speed without altering my game's FPS?

Tags: python, animation, pygame, sprite, frame-rate

I finally figured out how to animate my sprite, but now I have a new problem. When running the game at my desired FPS (60), the character animation is way too quick. The animation looks smooth at around 10FPS, but the game looks choppy at that framerate. It is possible for my game to run at 60FPS, while the animation runs at a seperate FPS (ex. 10)? Any help appreciated!

[Images and Sound FX Dowload](https://mega.nz/#F!7O5zRQDK!YQhrs_zavCvdSdAMwEXEIQ)

My code:

```
import pygame
import random
import time
import os
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d, %d" %(0, 20)
pygame.init()

SIZE = W, H = 400, 700
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# colours
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
BACKGROUND = (94, 194, 222)
STRIPE = (60, 160, 190)
LANELINE = (255, 255, 255)

x1 = 30
x2 = 330
lane1 = 30
lane2 = 130
lane3 = 230
lane4 = 330
y = 530
width = 40
height = 64

toggle1 = 0
toggle2 = 0

target_x1 = 30
target_x2 = 330
vel_x = 10

def drawScene():
    screen.fill(BACKGROUND)
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, STRIPE, ((200, 700), (300, 700), (400, 600), (400, 500)))
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, STRIPE, ((0, 700), (100, 700), (400, 400), (400, 300)))
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, STRIPE, ((0, 500), (0, 600), (400, 200), (400, 100)))
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, STRIPE, ((0, 300), (0, 400), (400, 0), (300, 0)))
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, STRIPE, ((0, 100), (0, 200), (200, 0), (100, 0)))
    pygame.draw.line(screen, LANELINE, (100, 0), (100, 700), 2)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, LANELINE, (200, 0), (200, 700), 4)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, LANELINE, (300, 0), (300, 700), 2)


mainsheet = pygame.image.load("dolphinSheet.png").convert()
sheetSize = mainsheet.get_size()
horiz_cells = 6
vert_cells = 1
cell_width = int(sheetSize[0] / horiz_cells)
cell_height = int(sheetSize[1] / vert_cells)

cellList = []
for vert in range(0, sheetSize[1], cell_height):
    for horz in range(0, sheetSize[0], cell_width):
        surface = pygame.Surface((cell_width, cell_height))
        surface.blit(mainsheet, (0, 0),
                     (horz, vert, cell_width, cell_height))
        colorkey = surface.get_at((0, 0))
        surface.set_colorkey(colorkey)
        cellList.append(surface)

cellPosition = 0

# main loop

while True:
    clock.tick(60)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                pygame.mixer.music.load('percussiveHit.mp3')
                pygame.mixer.music.play()
                toggle1 += 1
                if toggle1 % 2 == 1:
                    target_x1 += 100
                else:
                    target_x1 -= 100
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                pygame.mixer.music.load('percussiveHit.mp3')
                pygame.mixer.music.play()
                toggle2 += 1
                if toggle2 % 2 == 1:
                    target_x2 -= 100
                else:
                    target_x2 += 100

    if x1 < target_x1:
        x1 = min(x1 + vel_x, target_x1)
    else:
        x1 = max(x1 - vel_x, target_x1)

    if x2 < target_x2:
        x2 = min(x2 + vel_x, target_x2)
    else:
        x2 = max(x2 - vel_x, target_x2)

    if cellPosition < len(cellList) - 1:
        cellPosition += 1
    else:
        cellPosition = 0

    drawScene()
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, (x1, y, width, height))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, (x2, y, width, height))

    screen.blit(cellList[cellPosition], (x1 + 4, y - 1))
    screen.blit(cellList[cellPosition], (x2 + 4, y - 1))
    # players
    # screen.blit(playerImg, (x1 + 4, y - 5))
    # screen.blit(playerImg, (x2 + 4, y - 5))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Quick version: You update your sprites distances/size/animation based on delta between now and the last render time - instead of updating a fixed value per render sequence. Something like (beware, this is crude): [this](https://github.com/Torxed/pyslither/commit/aeee2805329c8a1aa2dcc1b079608d87b4015da6#diff-5bc02cefb3ea9e27f1a6776eabd1935dR107)

Answer (score 0):

Update the image based on a real-time millisecond delay, rather than every frame.  Use `pygame.time.get_ticks()` (returns the number of milliseconds since `pygame.init()`) to update the image based on a specific time.

For example:

```
MS_FRAME_TIME = 100  # Mow many milliseconds a frame is shown for

...

last_paint_at = 0    # Start condition to ensure first paint

...

while True:
    clock.tick(60)

    ticks = pygame.time.get_ticks()  # millliseconds since start

    # If enough milliseconds have elapsed since the last frame, update!
    if ( ticks - last_paint_at > MS_FRAME_TIME ):
        last_paint_at = ticks

        if ( cellPosition < len(cellList) - 1 ):
            cellPosition += 1
        else:
            cellPosition = 0

        screen.blit(cellList[cellPosition], (x1 + 4, y - 1))
        screen.blit(cellList[cellPosition], (x2 + 4, y - 1))
```

If it fits your code, it may also be possible to simply look at the modulus of the time to select the animation frame.